# GeoServer - Horizontal Banding Between tiles

Tags: postgis, geoserver

Anyone know what is causing this banding between tiles:

[image: shows banding]

This is a PostGIS layer, imported from SQL Server into PostgreSQL using ogrfdw as outlined here: [Import SQL Server Spatial Data into PostGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/227031/import-sql-server-spatial-data-into-postgis)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are cut labels, the issue has been fixed in GeoServer 2.10.2. See https://osgeo-org.atlassian.net/browse/GEOS-7928