# Creating OGR FDW to Teradata ODBC from PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgis, ogr-fdw

In my PostgreSQL/PostGIS I need to create FDW to an instance of Teradata Database. My aim is to get attributic-nonspatial data from the Teradata. I opted to use OGR_FDW instead of ODBC_FDW as [this](http://www.postgresonline.com/journal/archives/372-ODBC-FDW-now-supports-9.5-and-9.6.html) article recommends OGR_FDW as the performance is generally better, and the fact that I am using PostGIS in my PostgreSQL DB.

In order to create the FDW with OGR_FDW I have to do several steps that include CREATE SERVER, CREATE USER MAPPING, and IMPORT FOREIGN SCHEMA. Unfortunately I can not find example specifically for Teradata ODBC. I need to now what are the accepted OPTIONS values for Teradata ODBC.

So then I read several reference: [(1)](https://github.com/pramsey/pgsql-ogr-fdw) by Paul Ramsey and [(2)](http://www.postgresonline.com/journal/archives/372-ODBC-FDW-now-supports-9.5-and-9.6.html)  by Leo Hsu & Regina  Obe .

The one from Paul Ramsey states that we can use command `ogr_fdw_info` to generate server and table definition, but I do not understand what is the `datasource` used in the  `ogr_fdw_info` call?

I have the config for the Teradata in my PostgreSQL server. As the PostgreSQL server is with Windows Server i made it in the ODBC Data Source Administrator 64-bit, as system Data Sources:

[image: (gambaR)]

And subsequent connection test was a success:

[image]

However, when I tried to use this `tdprod` in the `ogr_fdw_info` call, but the `ogr_fdw_info` does not recognize it:

[image]

I tried to create th remote server anyway, but failed:

[image]

Can anyone :

1. show me how to issue ogr_fdw_info with my Teradata ODBC so i can get the CREATE SERVER scripts? or
2. point me to example of setting up OGR_FDW to Teradata ODBC?

My environment is:

- PostgreSQL 9.6.1 64-bit & PostGIS 2.3.3
- Windows Server 2016 Standard, 64-bit
- Remote datasource: Teradata Database version 16.00.00.14
- Teradata ODBC Driver 16.20 64-bit

Comment: As per the [Tour] there should be only one question asked per question.

Answer (score 1):

Re 1.

If you want to use a registered ODBC DSN (e.g. 'tdprod'), you can run:

```
ogr_fdw_info -s "ODBC:tdprod"
```

May you need to authenticate (e.g. as '{user}' with a '{password}'), then:

```
ogr_fdw_info -s "ODBC:{user}/{password}@tdprod"
```

If ogr_fdw_info supports some database natively, you can also specify a whole specific connection string by yourself:

```
ogr_fdw_info -s "{protocol}:server={server_name};port={port};uid={user};pwd={password}[;{etc.}]"
```

Re 2.

OGR_FDW is a abstraction layer so creating a server for Teradata isn't different from creating a server for MS SQL except for a connection string you give in the server's options.

Some examples are:

a. SQL commands - http://www.postgresonline.com/journal/archives/339-OGR-foreign-data-wrapper-on-Windows-first-taste.html - and a very detailed post by Regina - [Import SQL Server Spatial Data into PostGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/227031/import-sql-server-spatial-data-into-postgis);

b. pgAdmin4 - https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/1.x/foreign_server_dialog.html
Please, note that in an ogr_fdw server's case you don't create explicit user mapping. If needed, it can be given implicitely in datasource connection string.