# Shapefile import failed in PostGIS

Tags: postgis, postgresql, spatial-join

I am new to PostGIS/PostgreSQL and have downloaded and installed to perform a spatial join which ideally takes 27 hours in ArcGIS Pro and 19 hours by ArcPy. Hoping for a faster results via PostGIS from what I read everywhere online.

I have installed both PostgreSQL and PostGIS. But I am unable to import a shapefile to the database. Basically I have a spatial table in SQL Server which is somewhat challenging to import to pgAdmin as I cannot figure out a way to connect the database of SQL Server using ogr_fdw. The answer [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/227031/import-sql-server-spatial-data-into-postgis) does not help as I believe there are some restrictions in the organization end causing a failure as it only takes windows authentication.

As a workaround I converted the spatial table to a shapefile using feature to feature conversion. But now I am unable to import the shapefile to PostGIS/PostgreSQL. I am using the shp2pgsql GUI for importing and its throwing out a "Error reading shape output" as an error.

[image]

Any suggestion to have my spatial table imported to PostGIS or a way to get the converted shapefile imported?

Comment: your shapefile geometry is of type `Polygon`, the table in PostGIS defined with geometry `MultiPolygon`. both need to be the same; try setting *Multipart to singlepart* in *Options* (haven't used that tool for a while, but that options should be there...)

Comment: @ThingumaBob Tried that as well but gives an error: 

Shapefile type: Polygon
PostGIS type: POLYGON[2]
We have a Multipolygon with 2 parts, can't use -S switch!

Shapefile import failed.

Comment: you know what, I was stupid; singleparts are exactly what you *don´t* want in a *MultiPolygon* table...,) you seem to have mixed geometry types (shapefile type 2 and 5 maybe?) in your shapefile, and `object 130996` is causing the import to fail.

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution ?

Comment: Shapefile is *not* an appropriate transfer mechanism between databases -- It corrupts NOT NULL columns, truncates field names, strips datetime fields to date resolution, truncates VARCHAR wider than 254 width, **and** has a 2GiB maximum file size in both `.shp` and `.dbf` (which you appear to be hitting here). File geodatabase wouldn't have any of these issues, but that's not the root problem. The *actual* issue here isn't poor join performance by Esri tools, but poor performance of the SQL Server table, probably due to a lack of spatial index. Drop and rebuild the spatial index.